# iOS: UITableView clarifications

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

How can I eliminate views created upon selecting a cell in UITableView when the cell is no longer selected or other cell is on selection.

Suppose I have the code below for didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    CGSize cellSize = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].frame.size;

    UIView *selectionView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, (int)cellSize.width, (int)(cellSize.height + 100))];
    selectionView.layer.borderWidth = 2;

    [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]addSubview:selectionView];

}
```

Now, I want to remove that created selectionView when I focus on another cell and create it again to the cell which I am focusing.. The problem is that when I select a cell for the first time, it works perfectly but when I select another cell, the selectionView created from the previous cell still does not disappear and it duplicates the view already. How am I suppose to solve this? Need suggestion.. :( thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `tag` for the `selectionView` as follows

```
selectionView.tag = 100;
```

Also , you need to have the reference of the last selected indexPath by declaring a `NSIndexPath` class member and retaining it.

So while selecting a new cell, get the cell with last selected indexpath and remove the view from the cell as follows

```
UITableViewCell *lastCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:lastSelIndexPath];
UIView *view = [lastCell viewWithTag:100];
[view removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: thanks aadhira... hehe we have the same guess and it works.. :D

Answer (score 1):

You really need to look into subclassing `UITableViewCell` if you want a custom selection UI. Then override `[UITableViewCell setSelected:animated:]` (or `[UITableViewCell setHighlighted:animated:]`) to perform your customisations.